# Получить все таблицы в базе, в которых есть колонка с определенным названием

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть база данных  SQL Server 2008 с большим количеством таблиц. Нужно получить список всех таблиц БД, в которых есть колонка с названием `Recorder_TYPE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select table_name 
from information_schema.columns
where column_name='Recorder_TYPE'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select [Sch].[name] as [Schema], [Tab].[name] as [Table], [Col].[Name] as [Column]  
from sys.tables as [Tab]  
    inner join sys.columns as [Col] on [Tab].[object_id] = [Col].[object_id]  
    inner join sys.schemas as [Sch] on [Tab].[schema_id] = [Sch].[schema_id]  
where [Col].[Name] = 'Recorder_TYPE';
```

В предыдущем примере в результате запроса будут получены также "несуществующие" временные таблицы View.